# How to share C code between different platforms

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I am writing a pair of C programs to communicate between a Linux host and a Raspberry Pi, via sockets. There is some shared code and data; and some general-purpose sockets functions.

My first thought was to put the common functions in an archive library. That seems like overkill as the library would have to be compiled on both platforms. The next idea is to use a common file that would be `#include`'ed in both programs.

I know that it has always been frowned upon to put code in header files, so I am asking for any other ideas.

I only have a few hundred lines of code. It is a small hobby project for my own personal use, so nothing too heavyweight. Ease of maintenance, free of cost and future expandability are my main aims.

Comment: If you use a good build system, writing libraries is as simple as listing the source files needed for the library. You then tell the build-system which compiler to use for which sub-project, and the library should be automatically built for each target system. Even using `make` it's not that hard or complicated to use different target compilers for the PC and the RPi projects.

Comment: I cannot see why it would be overkill to compile them for both platforms.

Comment: What has h files to do with anything? One common way to design a HAL is to have a common API in a h file, then link different implementations of those functions depending on target.

Comment: Also, isn't Rasp PI some ARM and the Linux host some x86? How can you _not_ compile the project for both platforms then?

Comment: It's no problem putting code in header files... CImg at https://cimg.eu for example is 61,000 lines of **header-only** C++ library for image processing - no other libraries linked, or included. Very simple to add to a project!!! `#include "CImg.h"` and you're all done!

Comment: If you have more than a few lines of shared code, creating a library isn't overkill at all. It's a clean solution (and easy too, after you've done it once) which aligns nicely with your main goals (expandability & maintainability). A different (not recommended!) solution, which was used in our company for some old projects, would be to link the shared source files into the different project directories. I can't say how many times in my career i wanted to punch my predecessor(s) because of that.

Comment: That's what libraries are _for_.